# Excel Doesn't Auto-Fit 45º Text

Tags: vba, excel

When I orient column headers at 45º I have to manually resize each column since Auto-Fit won't let the oriented text overlap with the neighboring cell.

Is there a way to programatically (with VBA) auto-fit the columns where they'll overlap?  I'd like a solution which takes font size into account too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoFit only works on non 0º oriented text when the cell with the oriented text has borders set. Odd...

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is autofit to the cell range *excluding* the header row:

```
Sub autofitToRange()
    Range("B2:F5").Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Instead of:

```
Sub autofitFullColumns()
    Range("B:F").Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SheetName.Range("a:c").Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Will autofit columns a - c in Sheet `SheetName`. Is this what you were looking for?